# What is freshman undergraduate engineering enrollment in total nationwide in the US?

Tags: united-states, undergraduate, engineering

What is freshman undergraduate engineering enrollment in total nationwide in the US in three most recent years?

I mean the number in total from in every discipline of engineering field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the National Science Foundation's report ["Science and Engineering Indicators 2016"](https://www.nsf.gov/statistics/2016/nsb20161/#/), as of 2013, there were 124,437 full-time freshmen enrolled in engineering programs.  See Appendix Table 2-21, which also includes data from past years.  Their source is "American Association of Engineering Societies, Engineering Workforce Commission, Engineering & Technology Enrollments, Fall 2013 (2014)."  AAES doesn't appear to have any more recent data available.